# Handling dynamic memory for the pointer data members of the class?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Consider the following class

```
 class A
 {
        ClassF1 *ptrobjF1;
        ClassF2 *ptrobjF2;
        ClassF3 *ptrobjF3;

        A()
        {   
            ptrobjF1 = NULL;
            ptrobjF2 = NULL;
            ptrobjF3 = NULL;
        }
};
```

In the above class A,  i have three pointer data members for classes ClassF1,ClassF2 and ClassF3. Memory will be allocated for this classes whenever required. Probably there may arise situation that only memory for ptrobjF1 need to created (or) there may arise situaltion for all the three members memory need to be created.

Since the all the three pointers are public, it will be accessed by the end-user who is using the class.

say suppose i am creating the memory for one of the data member(ptrobjF1) in the class and i left other two data members as NULL. In such weird situation if any body access the data member outside the class as below

```
A obja;
(obja.ptrobjF3)->Some_function(); // Program crahses because dereferncing NULL
```

Is there is any design pattern to avoid accessing the Data members which is left unintialized?

Comment: Yeah, there is a pattern: `if(obja.ptrobjF3) (obja.ptrobjF3)->Some_function();` If you wan't to prevent accessing uninitialized pointers, make them private, and provide appropriate getter functions.

Comment: What should be the default behaviour if function not initialized? Should the used be able to call it? If not, the user should check for 0 anyway.

Comment: @πάντα-ῥεῖ If am using that pointer member in many places then it becomes difficult for me check nullness at every time

Comment: @vinothcse2000 As mentioned in the 2nd part of my comment, encapsulate these pointers then.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off making the pointers private members, then controlling their allocation through getter functions. An outline of this:

```
class A
{
public:
    ClassF1& getF1()
    {
        if (!ptrobjF1)
        {
            ptrobjF1 = new ClassF1{};
        }
        return *ptrobjF1;
    }

    A() : ptrobjF1{nullptr} {}    

    ~A()
    {
        delete ptrobjF1;
    }

private:
   ClassF1 *ptrobjF1;
};
```

Of course you should also implement error handling for when allocation fails, think about copy construction, what const-correctness you need to deal with etc.

...or you could (and should) sidestep some of the issues and just use a `std::unique_ptr`:

```
class A
{
public:
    ClassF1& getF1()
    {
        if (!ptrobjF1)
        {
            ptrobjF1 = std::make_unique<ClassF1>();
        }
        return *ptrobjF1;
    }

private:
   std::unique_ptr<ClassF1> ptrobjF1;
};
```

Comment: You do not need to test `ptrobjF1` for `NULL` before calling `delete` on it. Also, you should initialize `ptrobjF1` to `NULL` in the constructor of `A`.

Comment: Does getF1() return anything?

Comment: You should just cut the bad code from the top and show only the pretty good code at the bottom.

Comment: I figured that OP might not have knowledge of `std::unique_ptr`, so introduced it as an improved version of code they would understand easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use exceptions

```
class WrongAccess
{};

class A
{
private:
    ClassF1 *ptrobjF1;

public:
    ClassF1* getF1()
    {
        if( ptrobjF1 )
        {
            return ptrobjF1;
        }
        else
        {
            throw WrongAccess();
        }
    }

    A( )
    {
        ptrobjF1 = NULL;
    }
};


A obja;
//Do something 
...
try{

    obja.getF1()->SomeFunc();
}
catch(WrongAccess &e)
{
    ///some handling
    ...
}
```